# javascript get selected html elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

User is on a webpage , uses his mouse to select stuff, how can i use javascript to know what has been selected?

Comment: Do you want the nodes, or just the text?

Comment: If you wanted the nodes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220478/get-all-dom-block-elements-for-selected-texts

Answer (score 3):

To get the raw text currently highlighted on the page you can do something like this:

```
function getSelectedText() {
    return window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() 
                               : document.selection.createRange().text;
}
```

Check an example of the above code [here](http://jsbin.com/azaya).

More info:

- [DOM Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection)
- [IE document.selection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535869%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the user dragging his mouse over text so that it's highlighted, use the Selection and Range objects (for Mozilla) and Selection and TextRange objects (for IE).