# How to iterate over every node in a selected range in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, textselection

When implementing a rich text editor in javascript, I need to apply some changes to every text node in selected range. Range object provides interface to get `startContainer`, `endContainer`, `startOffset`, `endOffset` for the selected range. How can I iterate over every DOM node in between?

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRange(0);
// How can I iterate over every node within the range?
```

Comment: Does [an example on accessing the range DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4220888/2579117) get you up to speed?

Comment: @RogierSpieker That points me in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As suggested, you can use `NodeIterator` to walk inside `range.commonAncestorContainer`.

Here's a snippet:

```
var _iterator = document.createNodeIterator(
    range.commonAncestorContainer,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL, // pre-filter
    {
        // custom filter
        acceptNode: function (node) {
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
        }
    }
);

var _nodes = [];
while (_iterator.nextNode()) {
    if (_nodes.length === 0 && _iterator.referenceNode !== range.startContainer) continue;
    _nodes.push(_iterator.referenceNode);
    if (_iterator.referenceNode === range.endContainer) break;
}
```

You should use `NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL` because your range can contain multiple [nodeTypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType). If you know what you are selecting, you can check [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator/whatToShow) to properly choose `NodeFilter`.

---

**Edit:** I also want to point out [document.createTreeWalker()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker).

The key difference is that `document.createTreeWalker()` allow your `acceptNode` filter to return both `NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT` and `NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP` with real differences.

**Quote from [NodeFilter docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeFilter):**

> FILTER_REJECT:
>
> Value to be returned by the NodeFilter.acceptNode() method when a node should be rejected. **For TreeWalker, child nodes are also rejected. For NodeIterator, this flag is synonymous with FILTER_SKIP.**

**Ps:** the [NodeFilter.acceptNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeFilter/acceptNode) documentation for `NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT` is incorrect.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think not using NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL would potentially result in the first condition always evaluating to false, as referenceNode might never equal startContainer if it was filtered away.

Answer (score 6):

`range.commonAncestorContainer` will give you the node that encompasses the range. If it gives you a text node, then that's the only node in your range.

If it gives you an element, you can use `NodeIterator`, or `el.querySelectorAll('*')` to get the nodes within.

Not all of these will be inside your range, so use `range.intersectsNode(el)` to confirm.

Comment: `Range.intersectsNode()` has no support on IE (up to and including 11) :(  Likewise `Selection.containsNode()`.